# 'TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index' when extracting elements from array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to pull certain indices from an array column of a dataframe by calling the index from a 1D array.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

i = np.arange(10)
range1 = np.where((i>=0) & (i<=2))
range2 = np.where((i>=3) & (i<=4))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
df['arr'] = df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']].values.tolist()
df
```

I used this method to extract the elements-

```
df['arr1']=df['arr'].apply(lambda x:itemgetter(*range1)(x))
df['arr2']=df['arr'].apply(lambda x:itemgetter(*range2)(x))
```

But got the error-

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I tried converting the ranges to type integer using-

```
df['arr1'] = np.array(df['arr'])[range1.astype(int)]
```

But got the error-

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

So then I tried-

```
df['arr1'] = np.array(df['arr'])[int(range1)]
```

But got the error-

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
```

Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

When you define both ranges, change your code to:

```
range1 = i[np.where((i>=0) & (i<=2))]
range2 = i[np.where((i>=3) & (i<=4))]
```

i.e. create an array containing **elements of *i*** indicated by *where*,
so the result is also *ndarray* with respectively filtered content.

Note that `np.where((i>=0) & (i<=2))` alone yields a **generator
comprehension** containing `(array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64),)`, i.e.:

- a **tuple** composed of a single element,
- this element is a *ndarray* containing *[0, 1, 2]*.

So such tuple cannot be used as an argument of *itemgetter*, but after the
proposed change in your code each *range* contains a *Numpy* array,
which you can use there.

Another 2, probably more natural solutions: Define both ranges as plain
*pythonic* lists:

```
range1 = [0, 1, 2]
range2 = [3, 4]
```

or *Numpy* arrays:

```
range1 = np.arange(3)
range2 = np.arange(3, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but in my case i is a 2000 element 1d array and I wish to extract the position of indices within a specified range from that array so that I can pull the items from my dataframe's array column at those very indices . So I don't want the elements of i indicated by where since the ranges 1 and 2 are not specifically in the order 0, 1, 2, 3...I want the indices themselves.

Comment: For example, I'm trying to extract the indices from i where the values range from 100 to 200 and the corresponding indices turn up as [306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318], and I then want to extract the values from my dataframe's array column at those indices.

Comment: To extract elements of a *Series* (say *s*) from given indices use *s.loc[indices]*.